# convert base64 image to tensor

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I'm sending the image as base64 string to the node express server to analysis the object detection with tensorflow. How to change the base64 image as tensors for object detection with cocossd model in node js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**server side NodeJs**

The base64 string can be converted to binary and then be read as tensor using `tf.node`

```
 const b = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64')
    // get the tensor
 const t = tf.node.decodeImage(b)
```

If other properties/values are not sent along the request, it would be best to send directly the image as binary in a post request or in a websocket. In that case, there would be no need to redo the conversion from base64 server side

**browser side**

```
const b = atob(base64str)
let byteNumbers = new Array(b.length);
for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = b.charCodeAt(i);
}
let tensor = tf.tensor(byteNumbers)
```

This first option is synchronous. For big image it can possibly freeze the main thread. To alleviate that, this operation can be done in a web-worker.

The other option would be to create an image element and set it href attribute to the `base64str` and then use `tf.browser.fromPixels`

```
function load(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const im = new Image()
        im.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
        im.src = 'url'
        im.onload = () => {
          resolve(im)
        }
   })
}

// use the load function inside an async function   

(async() => {
     const image = await load(url)
     let tensor = await tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
   })()
```

Comment: On server side node.js tf.tensor(b, shape) what the value shape should have?

Comment: second solution I'm getting the error as The shape of dict['image_tensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,-1,-1,3], but was [1,629051]. @edkeveked How should I give the shape to the tensors.

Comment: The shape should be `[height, width, channels]`. You need to know the width and the height of the image. You can add a batch dimension (most left position) which will make the shape to be `[b, height, width, channels]`. The difference when you use tf.fromPixels, it returns directly a 3d or 4d tensor

Comment: _{
  base64: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAA........',
  width: 722,
  pictureOrientation: 1,
  deviceOrientation: 1,
  height: 1280
}_ Its my base64 image resolution. The code which I'm using in server is
`let buff = Buffer.from(data.photo.base64,'base64')
let tensor = tf.tensor(buff,[data.photo.height,data.photo.width,3])`
But I have the error on getting tensors as **Based on the provided shape, [1280,722,3], the tensor should have 2772480 values but has 610963**

Comment: @Jayaprakash did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
const readImage = path => {
 //reads the entire contents of a file.
 //readFileSync() is synchronous and blocks execution until finished.
 const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
 //Given the encoded bytes of an image,
 //it returns a 3D or 4D tensor of the decoded image. Supports BMP, GIF, JPEG and PNG formats.
 const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
 return tfimage;
}
```