# Implementing TensorFlowjs model in Ionic framework with Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, tensorflow.js, capacitor

I am working on a project where I am using Ionic and TensorFlow for machine learning. I have converted my TensorFlow model to a tensorflowjs model. I have put the model.json file and shard files of the tensorflowjs model in the assets folder in Ionic. Basically, I have put my tensorflowjs model in the assets folder of ionic. I am wanting to use Capacitor to access the camera and allow users to take photos. Then, the photos will be passed to the tensorflowjs model in assets to get and display a prediction for that user.

Here is my typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

import { Plugins, CameraResultType, CameraSource} from '@capacitor/core';

import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

import { rendererTypeName } from '@angular/compiler';

import { Base64 } from '@ionic-native/base64/ngx';

import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';

const { Camera } = Plugins;

@Component({

  selector: 'app-predict',

  templateUrl: './predict.page.html',

  styleUrls: ['./predict.page.scss'],

})

export class PredictPage{

  linearModel : tf.Sequential;

  prediction : any;

  InputTaken : any;

  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  canvasElement : any;

  photo: SafeResourceUrl;

  model: tf.LayersModel;

  constructor(public el : ElementRef , public renderer : Renderer2 , public platform : Platform, private base64: Base64,

    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) 

  {}

  

  async takePicture() {

    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({

        quality: 90,

        allowEditing: true,

        resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,

        source: CameraSource.Camera});

      const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('src/app/assets/model.json');

      this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image.base64String);

      defineCustomElements(window);

    const pred = await tf.tidy(() => {

          // Make and format the predications

        const output = this.model.predict((this.photo)) as any;

                                

          // Save predictions on the component

        this.prediction = Array.from(output.dataSync()); 

        });

  }

}
```

In this code, I have imported the necessary tools. Then, I have my constructor function and a `takepicture()` function. In the takepicture function, I have included functionality for the user to take pictures. However, I am having trouble with passing the pictures taken to the tensorflowjs model to get a prediction. I am passing the picture taken to the tensorflowjs model in this line of code:

```
const output = this.model.predict((this.photo)) as any;
```

However, I am getting an error stating that:

> Argument of type 'SafeResourceUrl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tensor | Tensor[]'.\n  Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is missing the following properties from type 'Tensor[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

It would be appreciated if I could receive some guidance regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The model is expecting you to pass in a `Tensor` input, but you're passing it some other image format that isn't in the tfjs ecosystem. You should first convert `this.photo` to a Tensor, or perhaps easier, convert `image.base64String` to tensor.

Since you seem to be using node, try this code

```js
// Move the base64 image into a buffer
const b = Buffer.from(image.base64String, 'base64')

// get the tensor
const image = tf.node.decodeImage(b)

// Compute the output
const output = this.model.predict(image) as any;
```

Other conversion solutions here: [convert base64 image to tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758368/convert-base64-image-to-tensor)